# What's mechanism of emoticon code on facebook chat?

Tags: html, ajax, facebook

I have found the funny site [there](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.312323965468736.79926.312080468826419&type=3) :D

On your facebook chat dialog, you can push the emoticon photo code with the text on photo description like some facebook api code.

By using [FB Photo Zoom google chrome plug-in](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elioihkkcdgakfbahdoddophfngopipi), when I drag on each position on emoticon, they contain many emoticon codes like **[[xxxxxxxxx]]**

So my question is: how does the mechanism of Facebook chat allow users to post photos like this? Can we make the local images for use like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not emoticon codes, they're simple FB page or profile IDs.
e.g.

```
[[youtube]] // go to facebook.com/youtube
[[100001939588739]] // go to http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001939588739
[[biker.abhinav]] // go to http://facebook.com/bikerabhinav
```

All those rage faces, or any image which get replaced are actually page/profiles. [[xxxx]] just shows their thumbnail image.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is javascript that replaces those codes with images stored on the server  (the code is obfuscated, so I can't be sure).

You could do the same, you would just have to host the images yourself, and write a simple javascript file.